# How to get process information in PowerShell for runtime environment variables?

Tags: powershell

I want to get all the environment variables for a running process in PowerShell.
I know that I can get such information for startup settings using "Get-Process". If another service adds a variable on runtime these are missing here.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This is actually way more complicated than you'd think, because the only purveyor of this information is the kernel. The only nice, documented function is `GetEnvironmentStrings`, which only works for the calling process. If you want to go cross-process, you have to use `NtQueryInformationProcess` and `ReadProcessMemory` to grovel in some undocumented internals. It can be written, certainly, but I'm not aware of any ready-to-run code in C# (which could easily be hoisted into PowerShell). Consider if you really need this, or you can make do with a manual tool like Process Explorer.

Comment: Note that if you're merely interested in values passed to new processes after PowerShell was started, and not so much the environment variables for one particular process, that's much easier as you can just start a new instance: `powershell -Command 'dir env: | Select name, value | ConvertTo-Csv' | ConvertFrom-Csv`.